# Behaviour of shortcut assignment and normal assignment for float

Tags: java, compiler-errors, floating-point

I have a simple doubt

```
float k = 0;        
k+=0.2;     
k=k+0.2; // here compliation error
```

compliation error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from double to float`
My question is  **why not a complilation error at `k+=0.2;`**

Comment: Note that `k = k + 0.2f;`, the current recommended solution in the answers below, is different from `k = (float) (k + 0.2);`. The latter sets `k` to the `float` nearest to the mathematical sum of the current value of `k` and 2/10 more often than the former, if that is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2):

> 15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators
>
> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So the `+=` operator has a built-in cast to the destination type.

In contrast, the [clause for simple assignment says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1):

> 15.26.1. Simple Assignment Operator =
>
> A compile-time error occurs if the type of the right-hand operand cannot be converted to the type of the variable by assignment conversion (§5.2).

[Clause 5.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2) allows widening conversions but does not allow narrowing conversions. So, in `k+.2`, the constant `.2` has type `double`, and this causes the expression to have type `double`, and a `double` expression may not be directly assigned to a `float` object; it requires an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

In Java by default decimal number consider as double.

Float numbers you need to append '`f`' or '`F`' at end of the number like this `k=k+0.2f;` or `k=k+0.2F;`

Comment: Thats OK but my Question is  why not a complilation error at k+=0.2;

Comment: 0.2 is double you need to cast it to float or append f to it like this 0.2f

Comment: This answer does not explain why `k+=.2;` and `k=k+.2;` are treated differently by the compiler (one receives an error message and one does not).

Answer (score 1):

Java assumes literal decimal values are doubles. You need to explicitly put an "f" or "F" after the value to force it to be a float.

Comment: This answer does not explain why `k+=.2;` and `k=k+.2;` are treated differently by the compiler (one receives an error message and one does not).

Answer (score 0):

If Java allowed widening conversions from `double` to `float`, as well as `float` to `double`, then assignments like yours would compile fine, but expressions such as `someFloat == someDouble` would be ambiguous.  To avoid such ambiguity, Java regards all primitive types in sequence such that each type may be converted to the next higher type, but not vice versa.  Even though the percentage of implicit float-to-double conversions which represent programming mistakes far exceeds the percentage of implicit double-to-float conversions that would do so(*), the desire to arrange types into a strict sequence while avoiding having `someFloat == someDouble` translate as `someFloat == (float)someDouble` motivated type-casting rules which allow constructs which are more likely than not wrong to be done without typecasts, while requiring typecasts in cases where the behavior would be obvious without them.

In your cast, the compiler could be made not to squawk if you either specify that a constant is a `float` rather than a `double`, by adding an `f` suffix, or else avoid using `float` and simply use `double`.  I would generally advise the latter approach.  If you use `float` and later change your variables to type `double`, your maths will be compile fine but yield erroneous results unless you remove the suffixes from your constants (and also remove any explicit typecasts to `float` of things like function return values).  A statement like `double d=0.1f;` will set `d` equal to precisely 13421773/134217728 (i.e. 0.100000001490116), a value substantially larger than was probably intended, without any compiler squawk whatsoever.

Comment: This answer does not explain why `k+=.2;` and `k=k+.2;` are treated differently by the compiler (one receives an error message and one does not).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Sorry I hadn't caught that part originally.  I believe what's happening there is the same rule that allows the `+=` operator to work with things like `byte`.  If statement `byte1 += byte2;` were simply equivalent to `byte1 = byte1 + byte2;`, the assignment would be disallowed because it would require storing an `int` into a `byte`.  The statement is thus translated as `byte1 = (byte)(byte1 + byte2);`.  It is perhaps curious that `float1+=double1;` would be translated as `float1=(float)(float1+double1);`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: That the statement is processed as shown, rather than as `float1=float1+(float)double1;` may be demonstrated with `float f1=0.1f; f-=0.1;`.  If one subtracted 0.1f from f1, the result would be 0.0, but instead the result is the residue from the `double` 0.1.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: It is perhaps curious that Java allows one to achieve the semantics `float1=(float)(float1+double1);` without having to write it out in the "long" form above, even though allowing such semantics not only requires accepting an implicit double-float conversion but is ambiguous as to intent, but the compiler won't accept something like `someFloat = 0.1;` even though there's only one plausible thing the latter statement could mean if allowed.